# Cannot Access New Installation of MySQL on an Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I installed MySQL server on an Amazon EC2 instance and started it. Seems like it started, but when I try to do `mysql -u root` I get this error.

```
mysql -u root

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using       password: NO)
```

I don't have a password for the root and don't know how to go forward. 
How do I access the new installation?

Answer (score 4):

While others are suggesting a full reset of the MySQL `root` password via launching into single user mode and then reseting the password manually through a query, that should not be the case on a clean install.

And though this question is from 2015, it’s unclear what version of MySQL is being used. So that said, using MySQL 5.7, the process of getting a password on a clean install has changed. A temporary password is now set in the MySQL daemon log file which *should* be in this location:

```
/var/log/mysqld.log
```

But could also be in this path:

```
/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
```

As explained here [in the official MySQL 5.7 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html#yum-repo-starting-and-stopping-server) the password is in that error log and can be found using Grep like this:

```
grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

You can now login to MySQL using that password by running this command and entering that password when prompted:

```
mysql -uroot p
```

Or you can run `mysql_secure_installation`—which is good practice regardless—and enter and change the password there with that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the password reset is as follow:

```
service mysql stop
service mysql start --skip-grant-tables
mysql
```

Once logged in, set the password like this

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('whateverpassword')
WHERE user='root' and host='localhost';
```

Exit mysql client, and run

```
service mysql restart
```

That's it. You could now login with root@localhost's new password

```
mysql -uroot -p
```